# By giving Worksheets(index).Unprotect, button in Excel is not working

Tags: vba, excel

We are using Excel file to upload data to DB.There having many sheets in that excel.in first sheet having a button (named Export) to export all the data from remaining sheet to DB. An in one sheet i have written locking cells based on logic.Following is the code.

```
Function LockingExpiryDateCells(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal ExpDateColOffset, ByVal Expdate As String)
Dim rowCount As Integer

rowCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' get the count of rows that contains records
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Cells.Locked = False

If (ExpDateColOffset >= 0) Then
    Target.Cells.Offset(0, ExpDateColOffset).Value = Expdate
End If

For i = 7 To rowCount 
    If (Cells(i, 4) = "A") Then  
        Cells(i, 7).Locked = True 
    Else
        Cells(i, 7).Locked = False 
    End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

End Function

While Exporting(by clicking Export button) I got the following Error.
[image]
While googling I conslude that this is beacuse of protecting the sheet(There is a macro is running for each sheet for validating contents).
So I given the Code to avoid that error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Worksheets(Index).UnProtect
End Sub
```

Then that error is vanished. and all working fine in my system. So I deployed to QA. While testing I noticed that Export button is disabled all the time.

When I reverted the changes, the button enabled.

I can't find out any solution to fix this issue.

Please give any solutition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Index** is a global variable?

Comment: When you say you are clicking the Export button, do you mean a button you named Export and has code with it?  If so, what all goes on in that code?  Is there a value trying to be written to a protected sheet in there?

Comment: @ Maciej Los : No for understanding i just given 'Index' - it will be a numeric value.

Comment: @peege:  Yes you absolutly right. button named "Export".And that has a code, before the code get executing the button is disabled. When I uninstalled the MS office service pack 2 and rebuild the code in Service pack 1, then that button become ENABLE.

Answer (score -1):

If you have password you should add [optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841143%28v=office.15%29.aspx) parameter.

> rowCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Here and in following cases try add sheet address like:

> rowCount = Sheet(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Do you see any password with Protect method in OP's code? I don't.

Comment: @MaciejLos Maybe Sheet is protect by password set by user before executing the macro.
If you don't have access to cell, system will return 1004 error.